# Curiosity about a deleted question.

Tags: discussion, support, deleted-questions

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3967159/constructing-non-fundamental-solutions-to-pells-equation-with-a-given-abscissa) has been deleted, but I'm still a little curious about the claim. This is not the first time I have been curious about a question, but later I find out that it has been deleted. I'm not the site moderator, and I'm not aware of all aspects. I think deleting questions should be everyone's right. But sometimes you put your energy into a question and you are curious about it. I think it might be helpful to apply some restrictions to delete the questions. I emphasize that I am not the moderator of this site, and I am not aware of all aspects.

Comment: It seems you were more than curious about the question; you actually answered the question.  The OP (asker) deleted their question.  If there are no upvoted or accepted answers, the asker is free to delete their question.

Comment: Related to the question as this is stated currently: [Is it okay to re-ask a deleted question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29136) (However, it was pointed out in the previous comment that you actually answered that question. Which perhaps makes the situation a bit different.)

Comment: Dear @amWhy if you meant the comment I didn't verify its details, but I strongly feel it contains a good idea for a counter-example. That's the reason why I returned back to that question because I want to check that if this gives the correct answer or not.

Comment: Dear @MartinSleziak that's one of the reasons why I ask this question here. I was curious if I was allowed to ask a deleted question again? Or not? Another problem I have encountered is that in the past I have sometimes observed people around me asking for their assignments here, without mentioning that it is an assignment. I once reported this issue on this site, which unfortunately did not accompany me. It does not matter to me, but if one day I become a university professor, it is important to me that my students do not abuse this site because of laziness and lack of interest.

Comment: Dear amWhy that answer is wrong, as it was pointed out by @DanielFischer. I mistakenly assumed that $d$ was fixed, when it was not, and Daniel Fischer pointed it out to me.

Comment: Dear amWhy This is my comment: After the comment by @GerryMyerson , if I had enough time, I would write a code that would start searching in the following consecutive numbers: $\{x=n^2+2,n^2+3,n^2+4,n^2+5,n^2+6\}$, such that except for $1$ and $4$, no other perfect squares does not divide the elements of the set $\{n^2+1,n^2+2,n^2+3,n^2+4,n^2+5,n^2+6,n^2+7\}$. For instance, $\{x=66,67,68,69,70\}$ (Also $\{x=83,84,85,86,87\}$) seems to be a good choice, but right now I can not verify which of these numbers is productive.

Comment: @Martin  The question you link to in the second comment does not resemble the question asked here. You merely put the idea in the head of Davood, as seen by his "dear MartinSleziak" comment to you.  Davood never asked anything close to that in the meta question here.

Comment: The at-sign can't be used to notify someone who has not taken part in this question, Davood. I was wondering, though, why OP deleted the question on main – I was hoping to see some clarification by OP in the light of my comment. I think there might be an interesting question lurking there, if we can only get it right. @amWhy, a user is not free to delete a question if the reason for deletion is to hide his/her tracks after posting homework/exam/competition questions without permission. We have seen such deletions reversed. I'm not saying that's the situation here.

Comment: I agree, @GerryMyerson.  I can't know whether that's the situation here, and I tend to think in general that it is bad form to delete a question after asking when others have been responding, even if only in comments.  It's just more difficult to establish that the question was a homework/exam/competition question used without permission.

Comment: For instance, [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3973496/is-there-any-surjective-homomorphism-varphi-mathbb-z-2-mathbb-z-times-math) is deleted right now (I can not see it). I am very suspicious if it was an assignment or not. (I should emphasize that the case of the question in my main question here, is different)